# android In-app Billing Version 3 初回購入

Tags: android

Google playの課金で魔法石のようなものを購入する場合に
初回購入を判定する方法は有りますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「何度も購入できる」ということは、独自サーバー側で購入履歴を管理することになると思うので、独自サーバー側で初回かどうかを判定するのはどうでしょうか？